# Core Data - Insert based by parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, swift

I have a table called Person.
How to make a data entry which are based by name, not to repeat the names.

Example:

> I have a person named Josh. Can not have another person named Josh.

Similar the function of PK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, CoreData doesn't have a built-in way to prevent dupes.

First, do a fetch request with a predicate to see if the value exists.  If it does not exist, then insert the new entity.

Example)

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    let personName = "Josh"

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", personName)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    var error: NSError?
    let fetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as [NSManagedObject]?

    if let results = fetchedResults {
        // if no results found, then insert
        if results.count == 0 {
            let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
            let person = Person(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
            person.setValue(personName, forKey: "name")

            var error: NSError?
            if !managedContext.save(&error) {
                println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
            }
        }

    } else {
        println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, CoreData doesn't have the logic of Primary key built in. Actually CoreData manage graph of objects that can be persisted,it's not strictly speaking an ORM.

So, you will have to make a request (using NSFetchRequest) to fetch objects with firstname Josh, if there is none you will add it, else you can update it.

It's possible to build security in your code to enforce that unicity rule with validateForInsert, validateForUpdate etc..
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/validateForInsert: